# Weird width on a link styling

Tags: html, css

Weird width on a class, for some reason when the link drops onto two lines the box displays at max-width leaving a lot of space to the right. Is there any way of resolving this without having to get rid of max-width? Would it be a case of using 2 seperate styles for multi-line/single line?

Thanks

[image: screenshot]

```
{
position: absolute;
left: 190px;
padding: 4px 8px;
top: 100px;
font-size: 0.9em;
font-weight: 400;
max-width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle code where we can see your HTML and CSS?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: What information does that give me Liam? I havn't pasted a link to a website apart from a screenshot? I have provided CSS that I have written and now have an issue with it, I thought that was the purpose of Stackflow, to ask questions/get some help etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because those two words are larger than 110px width. Since your `max-width` is 110px it is not extending.

You can use ellipsis to truncate the text

```
a{
    position: absolute;
    left: 190px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    top: 100px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 400;
    max-width: 110px;
    background:red;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9q778/)**

Comment: I guess his question is about the right padding not about the line break

Comment: @jantimon I knw but he should understand that max-width will occupy the max width even though text breaks

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and now it makes sense, unfortunately not a valid option for me, they want it to drop onto two lines but moaning about the spacing issue.

Maybe I need to set two different styles, one for 2 lines one for single line :/

Comment: @DamianSmith It's still the answer to the question though. If you want the width to be as large as the widest word, you should put a `<br>` in the text instead of a space.

Comment: @DamianSmith In that case you need to use auto width for a tag and max-width to parent element

Comment: @Sowmya the problem is that the width of the `a` _is_ `auto`. The natural width is, say, 200 pixels for those two words, so that's what it's trying to display at.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help guys, I have some just added to php script to basically strip out a space and replace it with<br> and seems to have done the trick, I will post up the code in a bit, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have a space directly after the opening tick and before the closing tick.

Comment: Basic gist of the code used: worked like a charm 

`$title_array = explode(' ', $title_orig);
if(is_array($title_array)){ $title = '';
$ti = 0;
foreach($title_array as $t){ if($ti > 0){ $title .= $t . ' ';
}else { $title .= $t . '<br>'; } $ti++; } }`

Comment: Better, thanks Mr Lister :)